# Laravel 5.7: what is the meaning of Undefined index style(mix('/css/frontend.css'))?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and currently attempt to import vue to my Laravel project.

After I ran 'npm run dev' command and check a page built with blade layout which is downloaded from a boilerplate project, I see the error : Undefined index in style(mix('/css/frontend.css')). This css file exists in public/css.

This is the line that invokes this error.

```
{{ style(mix('/css/frontend.css')) }}
```

What is its meaning and how to fix it?

Also, I can't find the api documentation that tell the function of style() and mix().
If you know where the documentation is, please give me the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `webpack.mix.js` to see if `frontend.css` is being compiled by Laravel Mix. If you don't see any reference to it, then you should reference the file in your Blade views with `asset('/css/frontend.css')` instead of `mix()`.

`mix()` reads from `public/mix-manifest.json` to map your source filenames to their output name, which is useful when files are versioned for cache busting. A mix-manifest entry might look like this: `"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=7564ad125f69af0035c3"`. If your file wasn't compiled or copied with Laravel mix then it would *not* have an entry in mix-manifest.json, which would explain the undefined index error and why you need to use `asset()` instead.

Also, I don't know what `style()` is but it doesn't come with the Laravel framework.

Refs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting